# Offline folder access on server

Tags: server, active-directory, windows-server, offline-caching

on file server we have folder with user home folders..

i would like to ask, is it possible to access home folder offline (without using VPN and connect to companys network) and how?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it can be possible but those file only which you have already sync in your local server . Please refer this link : https://www.minitool.com/backup-tips/sync-center.html

Answer (score 0):

•   Yes, you can access the ‘User\home folders’ directory through offline access also by enabling the option ‘Always available offline’ for that directory on the network file share and ensuring that ‘Sync center’ utility is enabled for managing offline files as below: -

1. Map the network drive on the system and access the file share for which you want to enable offline access. Then ‘Right click’ the share and select the option ‘Always available offline’ as below: -

[image: Always available offline]

2. Now, go to ‘ Control Panel --> Sync Center --> Manage offline files --> Enable offline files --> View offline files ‘ to check the shares on the network drive for which offline access is enabled. Also, ensure that network discovery, file and printer sharing, and password protected sharing is enabled as below: -

[image: Sync center offline files]
[image: Control Panel settings]

3. Once the above is done, go to Sync Center in Control Panel, select the offline task or folder displayed, right click it and select ‘Schedule for Offline files’ to select the specific directories or the whole content in the share to be scheduled to sync in the local disk storage reserved for offline access as below. Also, you can configure the offline accessible files disk usage limits through the sync center also by going to ‘Manage Offline files --> Disk Usage --> Change limits’: -

[image: Schedule for offline files]
[image: Offline files usage limits]

In this way, you can configure offline folders access through inbuilt Windows utility and access the desired folders offline after successful sync.